# Can a Unity game using the Google Maps Unity SDK be deployed to a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine

I have downloaded the Google Maps Unity SDK Demo (displays Manhattan, NY buildings and structures) and worked with in Unity on a Windows 10 PC successfully. This will not build to an executable as described in the documentation; the demo is a self contained data set. I do not have access to the developer version yet, but will the developer version of the Google Maps Unity SDK used in the Unity game engine build to an executable on a Windows 10 PC?

Can one develop a Unity game using Google Maps Unity SDK on a Windows 10 PC, but only deploy to iOS or Android and not to a PC?

I want to verify this in the context of the statement from the "Maps Unity SDK Overview" section of the "Google Maps Platform gaming solution guide". It contains the statement:

“Although Unity supports deploying games to over 25 platforms, the Maps Unity SDK supports deploying to just the iOS and Android mobile platforms.”

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Google states [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/overview_musk#supported_platforms) that the Maps Unity SDK is only supported on Android and iOS.

Furthermore, the minimum version of Unity that the Maps Unity SDK supports is v2018.4.  The Maps Unity SDK has no restrictions regarding the Android and iOS versions, however your version of Unity might have specific Android or iOS requirement. See [Platform Development Requirements for Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/system-requirements.html).

Hope this helps!